# How to send message to all the thread

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm

I'm learning distributed systems and while reading I learnt about Lamport Algo and also [this article](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/time-clocks.pdf).

Now I want to practically perform this algorithm, but I don't want to use different clients. I want to do this in threads. What confuses me is, how can a thread send a message to all the threads(different process) with the clock time?

If any one can give me structure how can I can do this Algo in Java that will be great.

Answer (score 3):

> So the confusion is how can a thread send a message to all the threads(different process) with the clock time ?

There are a number of ways to do this.  You need one thread to be able to send a message to all other threads (or at least the threads that care).  A message bus comes to mind with a publisher/subscriber mechanism.  One suggestion would be to use [Guavas' Event Bus](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/guavas-eventbus-simple-publishersubscriber.html).

Doing it by hand is going to be harder.  You could have each thread have a `BlockingQueue` for the messages and the publisher could add the message to all queues.  Maybe a utility class for threads to register and deregister themselves and their queues.

If you are using some sort of central shared queue or array of messages, the challenge is to know when all of the threads have consumed a particular message.

Comment: is there any other ways ?

Comment: I've added some more details @user2510115.